# Remove Messaging Webhook Programmatically from Twilio

Tags: c#, sms, twilio, messaging

Does anyone know of a way to remove a webhook in Twilio programmatically?

When I use the `Update` function in the Twilio library in C# and set the method, URL, and fallback URL to null, nothing changes in Twilio.  I need to be able to remove the webhook from Twilio via my program.

Thanks in advance!

```
IncomingPhoneNumberResource.Update(pathSid: phoneSid, smsMethod: null,
    smsUrl: null,
    smsFallbackUrl: null
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question.  In order to send back an empty URI for them to remove a webhook, you have to send back Twilio's `EmptyUri`.

```
var uri = new Twilio.Types.EmptyUri();
var phoneSid = "PNXXXXXXXXX";

await IncomingPhoneNumberResource.UpdateAsync(
    pathSid: phoneSid,
    smsUrl: uri,
    smsFallbackUrl: uri
);
```